# Changing timezone on redis server

Tags: redis

The `time` command on the `redis-cli` returns the current server time ([doc here](http://redis.io/commands/time)). How can I change the `timezone` on the redis server?

Note that redis gives me UTC timezone, whereas `date` on the Linux terminal shows me `UTC+5`, which is my correct timezone (Asia/Oral).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`time` command](http://redis.io/commands/time) is documented as using Unix time, which is UTC, so there's no way to change that. Timezone issues are complicated, so it makes sense for the Redis server not to concern itself with them.

Instead, convert it on the client using the libraries available on your platform.